# Getting resource file to MediaPlayer using string value java android?

Tags: java, android, string, resources, media-player

I am playing audios in a recyclerview when I click on an icon here is my code:

```
//Recyclerview onClickListener      holder.icon_audio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
String filename=    String.valueOf(model.getWordA());           Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(), R.raw.file);
mediaPlayer.start();                //mediaPlayer.release();
}});
```

Everything is fine only need to get kicked audio played with it's name from the variable that I get from model..

How to replace file with String in `R.raw.file` R.raw.filename?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure File Operations happens on IO Thread because it may consume a lot of time.

```
InputStream is = null;
FileOutputStream out = null;
Context context = view.getContext();
try {
    File tempFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "your_File_name");
    if (tempFile.exists()){
        tempFile.delete();
    }
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
    out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    copy(is, out);

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(tempFile));
    mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Log
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log
        }
    }
    if (out != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log
        }
    }
}

private void copy(final InputStream in, final OutputStream out)
    throws IOException {
    final byte[] b = new byte[8192];
    for (int r; (r = in.read(b)) != -1; ) {
        out.write(b, 0, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering please tell me how to use the string in R.raw.file   because I have a lise of files and the name in that static string  thanks 

Comment: to understand u correctly, u have a list of files in the Raw folder and u want to get the list of the files names in order to run them ? right ?

Comment: Yeah I have a list of files.mp3 in raw folder and names stored in recyclerview model I need to play the selected one by it's name I got selected name from model and I store it in static string variable the problem I am facing is with R.raw.filename how to replace that variable on it?